# "SET DEFINE OFF" is not working in Python cx_Oracle

Tags: sql, python-3.x, cx-oracle

```
con = cx_Oracle.connect(connection_string)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SET DEFINE OFF")
```

is throwing error:

DatabaseError
Traceback (most recent call last)
 in

```
  1 con = cx_Oracle.connect(connection_string)
  2 cur = con.cursor()
  3 cur.execute("SET DEFINE OFF")
```

DatabaseError: ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

Comment: `SET DEFINE` is a **sqlplus**  command, not a valid SQL command. You don't need it outside of sqlplus anyway

Comment: But I'm using it in Oracle SQL Developer which works fine. But need to run from python script.

Comment: SQL Developer simply tries to be compatible with sqlplus - But you do not need that option outside of the Oracle tools. It's an option for the **tool** (sqlplus or SQL Developer) - it is **not** a SQL statement.

Comment: So basically there is no way to run it through Python.

Comment: You do **NOT** need it in Python (and yes: you can't run that outside of the Oracle tools)

Comment: I'm trying to insert &-ampersand in column value. For this I need to SET DEFINE OFF. How to handle this in such case?

Comment: No. You do **not** need that outside of the Oracle tools.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in comments, SET DEFINE is a SQL*Plus command and is not interpreted by cx_Oracle.  You get the ORA error because cx_Oracle sends the statement to the database, and the database only handles SQL or PL/SQL statements.

You should use bind variables instead of the (unavailable) substitution variables.  Any kind of string substitution or interpolation is a scalability issue and security risk.  Bind variables solve these problems.  (Arguably you could have been using bind variables in SQL*Plus too).

Look at examples like [BindInsert.py](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/BindInsert.py):

```
rows = [ (1, "First" ),
         (2, "Second" ),
         (3, "Third" ),
         (4, "Fourth" ),
         (5, "Fifth" ),
         (6, "Sixth" ),
         (7, "Seventh" ) ]

cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.executemany("insert into mytab(id, data) values (:1, :2)", rows)
```

Check cx_Oracle documentation like

- [INSERT and UPDATE Statements](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/sql_execution.html#insert-and-update-statements)
- [Using Bind Variables](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#bind)
- [Batch Statement Execution and Bulk Loading](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/batch_statement.html#batchstmnt)

If you want to execute .SQL files, you will need to write some kind of parser that extracts SQL statements and executes them individually. And/or make sure that the .SQL file syntax regarding end-of-statement terminators is simplified.  For example, see how cx_Oracle uses this technique to install its sample schema via [RunSqlScript](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/7.3/test/TestEnv.py#L121-L154).